# In C# can you define an alias to a value tuple with names?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I know it's possible to define aliases in C# with the *using* keyword.

e.g.

```
using ResponseKey = System.ValueTuple<System.Guid, string, string>;
```

However, is it possible to define one using the new syntax for value tuples?

```
using ResponseKey = (Guid venueId, string contentId, string answer);
```

This syntax does not appear to work. Should it?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it looks very like the same as "may I use var at module-level to define a variable?"

Comment: if it doesn't compile means it shouldn't work

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it looks like it is better to create a class or struct for that purposes. Tuples are good, but please do not overuse it.

Comment: Interesing comment @YeldarKurmangaliyev. The reason for using this is to not have to implement all the comparable interfaces to use as a simple key for an object. Yes, it's me being lazy, but it is also using the language features to their fullest.

Comment: @NickRandell - most of the time you writing software for the people(other developers) - they will read your code. Having a class and properties with descriptive names - is more friendly/effective approach. Most of the times programmers spend on reading code(own and others) descriptive names and data structures will save their time

Comment: The first thing I thought when seeing tuples. When it is a type, it should be able to behave like this, I thought. However, neither `using X = dynamic;` nor even `using X = int[];`. So, it doesn't have to work.

Comment: Are you from a Python background, by any chance?

Comment: I'd like to see this work as well, it just seems natural. I can use `using Item = System.Tuple<int, int>` but not `using Item = (int, int)`. The latter is just as much the "name" of a type as the former, at least to a layman.

Comment: @Fabio I'm 100% for descriptive code, but what would be missing here? You'd have all properties properly typed with descriptive names and if OP will have his wish even a name for the data structure.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Updated. As of C# 10, you can define either a struct or class-based record to fulfill this requirement:

```
public record struct ResponseKey(Guid venueId, string contentId, string answer);
public record class ResponseKey(Guid venueId, string contentId, string answer);
```

Note that `class` is optional for the second definition.

---

[This has been requested, and recorded in the Roslyn repo on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15072). However it received a mixed reception there, and [the proposed record types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39), would more than cover this requirement.

The issue was closed in the Roslyn repo [but is now being tracked in the C# language repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/423).

Comment: issue was closed and moved to https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4284

Comment: "[...] record types, would more than cover this requirement" except they are classes...

Comment: @NoelWidmer, records can be structs in C# 10.

Comment: Worth noting another benefit: C# does automatic deconstruction for records, which makes them even more convenient (if you use deconstruction)!

Comment: one thing this loses is enumerability. with the `ITuple` interface I can enumerate the members of an arbitrary `ValueTuple`. I don't think there's a way to enumerate the members of a record (without going to reflection or something like that). (my goal is to have named members that are also enumerable but this is very difficult to achieve in a non-verbose way.)

Comment: @DaveCousineau, [it's easy to have a record implement `ITuple` though](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4GIYFcA2OLA4CmABETAcQLABQtAAgAwn0CMAdAEpYwAuUYIuwDCAezAAHKMQBOAZSIyAblADGRAM4BuWrRlFVomQhIbeMrKt4lOACljWAHnBIOSATwCUJECQCSACpYEtQ0AN60AJD0AMwkosAAVga8APwkvAAWUBoA2m5QALokALwAfK6mAO5QvKqZJBE0kZHM5STOUZGspRXucF0A+r0ZmTKiVSQwRJN+MAhEjgDyWLxLAGacEDAA5kQAoo7qEvyiMLYAREswOO6u84skzABkJD0Q+iRKEDhQJutGGwXTxRAC+OmaUVi92sABlyDssiMAEwQ0FAA===). And having a generalized form of this would be relatively straightforward to implement with a source generator.

Comment: @DavidArno hmm, that has to be implemented on each type, and has to be implemented with perfect accuracy each time to function correctly, and breaks as soon as you add a new member. what I did was use a record base type that adds new values to a static collection. you can then declare new static members in the inheritor that are named, and are also automatically enumerable from a static Values member. (requires the parent class to call the child class's static ctor with `RunClassConstructor`).

Comment: (this is instead of using a value tuple of value tuples which also can work, but the type becomes cumbersome to express without a type alias)

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible in C# 12 (preview) exactly the way you described.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/alias-for-tuple-in-c-sharp-12

Note that you need to specify the full namespace to the non-trivial types (there doesn't seem to be a way around this at the moment):

```
using ResponseKey = (System.Guid venueId, string contentId, string answer);
```

(this can be placed only in places where the normal 'using' statements are valid - you can't copy-paste this one-liner directly inside methods/functions so that it will be visible only to, say, local functions)